# RPG Battle, monsters health after attack with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I've asked about this before, because I'm still not too familiar with dictionaries, but what's happening is every time I attack the monsters health resets automatically:

```
#MONSTER STATS
corpsefinder_stats = {
    "corpsefinder_strength" : 7,
    "corpsefinder_speed" : 1,
    "corpsefinder_mana" : 0,
    "corpsefinder_health" : 45,
    }
#GAME START
if game_start==True:
time.sleep(0.6)
print(username, "wakes up, the cold snow on their face as they lie down in bewilderment, wondering where they could of come from and why they are here. As they stand up, they notice a small village in the distance, but before they can even begin to think of venturing over, a small bug-like creature approaches, primed for battle")
time.sleep(8)
while corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"] >= 1 or health >= 1:
    tutorialbattle=input("\nA CORPSE-FINDER gets ready to attack!\nWhat will you do?\n\n##########\n# Attack #\n##########\n\n##########\n# Defend #\n##########\n")
    tutorialbattle=tutorialbattle.lower()
    if tutorialbattle=="attack":
        corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"] -(random.randint(strength-10, strength))
        print(username, " attack!\nCORPSE-FINDER HP: ", corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"])
        print("CORPSE-FINDER attacks!\n", username, " HP: ", health-(random.randint(corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_strength"]-6, corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_stren
```

Comment: Your problem is not dictionary, it's basic programming. You should not do `myStat - randomValue` but `myStat=myStat-randomValue`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

`corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"] -(random.randint(strength-10, strength))`

you are just performing the mathematical operation, not assigning it to anything.

You need to do :

`corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"] = corpsefinder_stats["corpsefinder_health"] -(random.randint(strength-10, strength))`